# jquery show if from specific link

Tags: jquery, css

I have my site built with jquery show/hide divs and want to have a specific div show when the page is loaded from a specific link. Is this possible without URL parameters or creating a new page with inline styles to change the default div shown?

When the contact image is clicked from the home page: http://www.imsmfg.com/test/index.php it takes you to the about page: http://www.imsmfg.com/test/about.php with the contact div hidden. It's only from this link that I want to show the contact div first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript `document.referrer` property tells you where the page was loaded from.

Comment: I can use this for all the clicks from the home page, but I also have two other links that lead to the about page. Only when the contact image is clicked do I want to have the contact div show first. Is this possible to do?

Comment: You can't preserve javascript data when loading a whole new page, so you either need to do some server-side work or else pass a parameter in the URL. From the server side, you could, for instance, link to a dummy page that then redirected to the page. Then document.referrer would contain a different page.

Comment: Another way would be to use the contact click to submit a hidden POST form. Your contact page could then insert a javascript value when it sees that POST value come in, and you could open the div appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do the submit POST for this link. I will definitely use document.referrer in the future, wasn't familiar with it before.

Comment: The only caveat with the POST is that a browser BACK will try to re-submit the POST, along with the annoying "do you want to resubmit" junk. You could use a GET URL parameter query via a URL re-write on the server, so that site.com?var=this would be rewritten to just site.com.